# What are the differences between Stripe, Judo Payments and Braintree?

Tags: android, ios, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, braintree

I need to choose a payments platform for a native app and have the 3 options; Stripe, Judo Payments and Braintree.

Can anyone offer me some help on how they differ from each other and the pros and cons of all three.

If you have integrated a mobile payments solution in app which one would you choose and why?

Any help with this would be really helpful.

Thanks guys

Comment: Check out my answer at here, it has useful links for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583292/payment-gateway-usage-query-for-iphone-app/28591707#28591707

Answer (score 1):

We have developed and support a number of native apps and we use Stripe but Judo Payments have some interesting additional features such as their new independently created SDK for Xamarin which makes them interesting as that's why we went with Stripe due to Xamarin building an SDK on behalf of Stripe.

Stripe is a very simple integration but with pricing, lack of features and IMO lack of knowledgeable support am also looking for a new provider.

I have been speaking to Judo about switching as after talking to a technical sales guy, the pipeline of features is growing and the benefits of the Xamarin SDK alongside their mobile fraud solution seem to have very good reviews from our contacts.

I can't comment on Braintree but as they are part of Paypal now, and having worked with Paypal in the past I would avoid.